# HTML Hidden input not working table insided form

Tags: php, html, mysql

I need to echo `$_POST['selected_for_del']` but the problem is I am not getting proper id which is placed in html hidden input. What am I doing wrong? Is there something wrong in the hidden input?

```
<?php
$q = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM news_post LIMIT 30");
echo '
<form action="" method="post">
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>POST ID</th>
    <th>Post Title</th> 
    <th>Menu Name</th>
    <th>Is it event?</th>
    <th>Is it top?</th>
    <th>Is it roling?</th>
    <th>Delete Post</th>
  </tr>
  ';
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($q)) {
    $post_id = $row['post_id'];
    $post_title = $row['post_title'];
    //$post_text = $row['post_text'];
    $menu_name = $row['menu_name'];
    $is_event = $row['is_event'];
    $is_roling = $row['is_roling'];
    $is_top = $row['is_top'];
    $img_name = $row['img_name'];

    //return_yes_no_on_true_false($is_event);
echo '
    <tr>
    <td>'.$post_id.'</td>
    <td><a href="post_id='.$post_id.'">'.$post_title.'</a></td> 
    <td>'.$menu_name.'</td>
    <td>'.return_yes_no_on_true_false($is_event).'</td>
    <td>'.return_yes_no_on_true_false($is_top).'</td> 
    <td>'.return_yes_no_on_true_false($is_roling).'</td>
    <td><input type="hidden" name="selected_for_del" value="'.$post_id.'"></td>
    <td><br><input type="submit" name="submit_delete" value="Delete it"><br></td>
  </tr>
';
}
echo '</table></form>';


if (isset($_POST['submit_delete'])) {
    echo $_POST['selected_for_del'];
}

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a single form, so when you submit it, you are submitting **all** of your hidden inputs.

Since you want to know the input associated with the submit button that was clicked, and since there are no other form controls on the same row, you have two options:

**Forget about the hidden input**

Store the data on the submit button instead.

```
<button name="selected_for_del" value="<?=htmlspecialchars($post_id);?>"> Delete it</button>
```

**Put the form in a cell**

Don't put a form around the whole table. Put a separate form around each submit button, within the table cell that holds the button. Move the hidden input into that cell.

```
<td>
    <form method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="selected_for_del" value="<?=htmlspecialchars($post_id);?>">
        <input type="submit" name="submit_delete" value="Delete it">
    </form>
</td>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try placing the form within the loop ... when you print it out, you have many hidden inputs with the same name and different values in that one form.

Comment: Correct, and sorry.. If you want your entire form inside the td it would work and be allowed as @Quentin explains.

Answer (score -1):

Your problem is that the form is outside your loop and the name if your hidden input is the same for all rows, the result is that you always will remove your last row.

It's not the most optimal solution, but I would recommend the following:

1) Remove your hidden input.

2) Replace:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit_delete" value="Delete it">
```

with

```
<button type="submit" name="selected_for_del" value=".$post_id.">'Delete it'</button>
```